How to arrange Tile icons in single window in Sharepoint 2016
I have created a Promoted links of around 14 document library. In the Landing page i've added the Promoted link using App part.
The 14 tiles icon now appear in single row and have to press the left right arrow button to navigate.
How do i make the tiles appear in single window? In the screenshot is the image of desired tile appearnce.
Using Sharepoint 2016 on prem.
Thank you in Advance

it's called a slider, it's developed with created from JavaScript.

@MikhailZhuikov The image is actually the Promoted Links list template.

@Christoffer, Thanks Christoffer, in general as an option, but I prefer good old JS+CSS for such solutions, and not another crutch.

You can add some CSS in a script editor web part to the page to hide the arrows and then tinker with the width to get the expected results.
Try incrementing with 160 pixels for each tile you want on the same row - so for six on each row, try 960 pixels.
<style type="text/css">
.ms-promlink-body {
    width: 160px;
}
.ms-promlink-header {
    display:none;
}
</style>


Can the changes be made from Gui edit page interface ? im no programmer

In the web Part- Height and width is set to " Adjust Width to Fit Zone". Changing the height and width made no difference. The 14 Tile icons still continue to be in single Row .

You don't need to be a programmer. You just add a Script Editor Web Part just like any other web parts to a page - through the user interface. It's no way of doing it by changing the width or height through the web part properties.

You'll find it under the fold "Media and Content" when adding a web part.

Thank you very much. i did it after adding the script editor and used you code ,640px

Glad I could help. :)
